# Drawing a radius on a datapoint and counting other points in that radius

Tags: python, geolocation, geospatial, geo, qgis

Let's say I have two geographical datasets containing only points. For each point of dataset A, I would like to draw a 1 kilometer radius, count the number of points type B inside that radius, and attach this value to dataset A.

Is this possible using QGIS or Python?

Thanks a lot,
E

Answer (score 0):

I think you can code a loop for drawing the cricle points with this libraries:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from osgeo import ogr, osr
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
import matplotlib.colors as colors
```

And then you write:

```
def createCircleAroundWithRadius(lat, lon, radiusMiles):
    ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
    latArray = []
    lonArray = []

   for brng in range(0,360):
       lat2, lon2 = getLocation(lat,lon,brng,radiusMiles)
       latArray.append(lat2)
       lonArray.append(lon2)

  return lonArray,latArray
```

As return you receives the array with the two coordenates. Then you can do a loop over dataset B and prove of his coordenates are insides all the points in the arrays

I hope it can help.

For info: https://stochasticcoder.com/2016/04/06/python-custom-distance-radius-with-basemap/

Regards!